# how to take a random number generated in sas and use that to populate a whole column in another dataset?

Tags: sas

I know how to generate a random date in sas but then I want to take that date and use it to populate a column in another dataset?

So for example I have a dataset with columns a,b,c called pop, and I want to add another column date but fill that column with the one random date generated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rand('integer', min, max)` to randomly generate an integer between a min and a max value, where the min and max values are your minimum and maximum dates. Do this on the first iteration of a data step, then retain its value throughout with `retain`.

```
data want;
    set have;
    retain rand_date;
    format rand_date date9.;

    if(_N_ = 1) then rand_date = rand('integer', '01JAN2020'd, today());
run;
```

Or, make it a macro variable.

```
%let min  = '01JAN2020'd;
%let max  = %sysfunc(today());
%let date = %sysfunc(rand(integer, &min, &max));

data want;
    set have;
    format rand_date date9.;

    rand_date = &date;
run;
```

Comment: You don't need the %sysfunc(putn()) calls.  %SYSFUNC() can handle both the date literal in &MIN and the integer literal in &MAX fine without that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data pop;
   do a = 1 to 3;
      do b = 1 to 3;
         do c = 1 to 3;
            output;
         end;
      end;
   end;
run;

data want;
   set pop;
   if _N_ = 1 then randdate = rand('integer', '01jan2023'd, '31dec2023'd);
   format randdate ddmmyy10.;
   retain randdate;
run;
```